# Events on jQuery created html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working code for 1 Room field that was created in HTML.  In my form I have an add room button and its working great.  So far so good.  Until i try to perform updates from the .keyUp even from jQuery.  It works on the ROom field that is in the Html.  But when I add a room and try to do it in that room field, it does nothing.  I have a feeling its because it was created after the fact the page loaded.

```
<fieldset id="Rooms" value="1">
            <fieldset id="RoomField" value="1">
            <input id="Room1Name" type="text" name="Room1Name" value="Room1"> - Foot Length = <input id="FL1" size="2" type="text" name="Room1L" value=""> - Foot Width = <input id="FW1" size="2" type="text" name="Room1W" value=""> - Area Sq/F = <input id="SQF1" value="0" type="text" size="2" name="SQF1" readonly>sq/f - Material: <select id="Mat1"><option></option><option value="1">Hardwood</option><option value="2">Laminate</option><option value="3">Carpet</option><option value="4">Sheet/Tile Vinyl</option><option value="5">Tile</option></select><button id="AddRoom" onClick="addRoom();" value="1" type="Button">+</button>
            </fieldset>
        </fieldset>
```

That is my form data that I have.

The code I have for the update information is here:

```
$('Rooms').keyup(function(){
    var i++;
    var Id = '#Out_' + this.id;
    var Val = this.value;
    var curNum = $(this).parent().attr('value');
    var SQFid = "SQF" + curNum;var FWid = "FW" + curNum;var FLid = "FL" + curNum;
    var FW = $("#FW" + curNum).val();
    var FL = $("#FL" + curNum).val();
    var sqf = FW*FL;
    $("#SQF" + curNum).val(sqf);$("#Out_SQF" + curNum).html(sqf);
    $(Id).html(Val);
});
```

my function for the addRoom is:

```
function addRoom() {
    var num = $('fieldset[id^=RoomField]').length;
    num++;
    var html = '<fieldset id="RoomField' + num + '" value="' + num + '"><input id="Room' + num + 'Name" type="text" name="Room' + num + 'Name" value="Room' + num + '"> - Foot Length = <input id="FL' + num + '" size="2" type="text" name="Room' + num + 'L" value=""> - Foot Width = <input id="FW' + num + '" size="2" type="text" name="Room' + num + 'W" value=""> - Area Sq/F = <input id="SQF' + num + '" value="0" type="text" size="2" name="SQF' + num + '" readonly>sq/f - Material: <select id="Mat' + num + '"><option></option><option value="1">Hardwood</option><option value="2">Laminate</option><option value="3">Carpet</option><option value="4">Sheet/Tile Vinyl</option><option value="5">Tile</option></select><button id="AddRoom" onClick="addRoom();" value="' + num + '" type="Button">+</button></fieldset>';
    var p = '<font id="Out_Room' + num + 'Name">Room' + num + '</font> - <font id="Out_FL' + num + '">0</font>\' x <font id="Out_FW' + num + '">0</font>\' - <font id="Out_SQF' + num + '">0</font>sq/F - <font id="Out_Mat' + num + '"></font><br />';
    $("#Rooms").append(html);
    $("#RoomsConsole").append(p);
};
```

The row that I have created in my test.html is working fine.  Its the row that I add after the fact that it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('Rooms').keyup(function(){
```

To

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#Rooms', function() {
```

Have a look at the jQuery documentation on `on`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: yes i forgot about this, it has been a while since i've developed any webpages.  However I do have 1 modification for what i need to be done as this would require more lines of code to get what I actually need.    $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function() {